# Binding the same function to diferent buttons Ionic v2

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic2, angular2-template

I created a eye icon button for password view/notview

but there is a page that I need to be the "recovery password" page

In this page there're 3 inputs with the same button attached to them...

When I click one, all of them becomes toggled.

How do I bind each one individually to the same function?

The code follows:

HTML

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-input placeholder="Senha antiga" [type]="isSenhaView ? 'password' : 'text'">
  </ion-input>
  <button ion-button icon-only item-right clear color="light" (click)="toggleSenhaView()"><ion-icon [name]="isSenhaView ? 'eye' : 'eye-off'"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-item>
```

TS

```
isSenhaView : boolean = true;
  toggleSenhaView():void{
    this.isSenhaView = !this.isSenhaView;
  }
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: its better to create a component

Comment: I did thought about that, but I don't really know how to build this component...  How should it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code sample:

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-input placeholder="Senha antiga" [type]="isSenhaView1 ? 'password' : 
       'text'">
   </ion-input>
   <button ion-button icon-only item-right clear color="light" 
      (click)="toggleSenhaView(1)">
      <ion-icon [name]="isSenhaView ? 'eye' : 'eye-off'"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
    <ion-input placeholder="Senha antiga" [type]="isSenhaView2 ? 'password' 
      :  'text'">
   </ion-input>
   <button ion-button icon-only item-right clear color="light" 
      (click)="toggleSenhaView(2)">
  <ion-icon [name]="isSenhaView ? 'eye' : 'eye-off'"></ion-icon>
 </button>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
   <ion-input placeholder="Senha antiga" [type]="isSenhaView3 ? 'password' : 
      'text'">
</ion-input>
   <button ion-button icon-only item-right clear color="light" 
     (click)="toggleSenhaView(3)">
   <ion-icon [name]="isSenhaView ? 'eye' : 'eye-off'"></ion-icon>
   </button>
</ion-item>



isSenhaView1 : boolean = true;
isSenhaView2 : boolean = true;
isSenhaView3 : boolean = true;

toggleSenhaView(x):void{
   switch (x) 
   {
    case 1: 
      this.isSenhaView1 = !this.isSenhaView1;
      break; 
    case 2: 
      this.isSenhaView2 = !this.isSenhaView2;
      break; 
    case 3: 
      this.isSenhaView3 = !this.isSenhaView3;
      break;                 
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, this works, but I was thinking about something more dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

You could easyly use 3 booleans inside your function

```
isSenhaView : boolean = true;
isSenhaView2 : boolean = true;
isSenhaView3 : boolean = true;
  toggleSenhaView():void{
    this.isSenhaView = !this.isSenhaView;
    this.isSenhaView2 = !this.isSenhaView;
    this.isSenhaView3 = !this.isSenhaView;
  }
```

Comment: This is an ugly solution, you would have to add a boolean per field, I agree with @Lakshay : it is better to create a component